# AuFS reads and writes from different branches

Tags: etc, aufs

I'm looking for a way to keep `/etc` files from a distribution intact, and keep any customizations in a separate partition, using AuFS to lay the customizations over the default files.

Is it possible to use AuFS `/dir1 + /dir2 = /aufs` such that:

1. Writes to `/aufs` go to `/dir1`;
2. Reads from `/aufs` get from `/dir2`?

The idea is that writes from the package management system always go to the vanilla partition, but reads come from the overlaid one. Removing a file in the overlay immediately exposes the underlying pristine file.